# Call an external js function from html

Tags: javascript, function, button, call

I have an HTML file with the following button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="muteaudio()" id="testButton">Mute</button>
```

In the head part i have

```
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

In this script i have the following function

```
function($, window, document, undefined) {

    function muteaudio(){
        alert("it works");
    }

}
```

I'm doing something wrong that is clear. But what is the correct way to call such a function?

Comment: do `<input type=¨button¨>` I do not think `<button>` is a thing

Comment: @arodebaugh `<button> ` is valid html., @user3398922 are you certain the script is being found? Open up the dev tools for your browser (using f12 and preferably with Chrome or FF) and look at the network tab. Do you see your js file? Next check your spelling.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gwYcO3a8GWXxIcm3tP2w?p=preview, probably the path you are giving to src is wrong. check if you see your file in console as @scrappedcola said

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the file is definitely loading via the F12(Developer Tool) then Sources tab.
2. Check that you have reloaded the page properly so the cache cleared and loaded the latest version of the file.
3. If the file is not there then check the path you are using, intellisense should help you find the file:
   `src="~"` using ~ should activate the intellisense and help to find the file.
4. If the file is there but it is still not working then try copying the script code into your HTML file then you can determine whether it is the File or Code that is the issue:

   `<script type="text/javascript">
    function muteaudio(){
        alert("it works");
    }
    </script>`
5. It may be the position of the file, try rending it in the footer.

**UPDATE**

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeLXY/45/) which works with the following code and a Snippet:

```js
function test() {
    alert("in function!")   
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="mute" />
```

Comment: I allready knew the file was loaded correctly. Can check if it works from the footer area. I also edited the js file since I forgot to mention a line that all the js is in

Comment: If i add an alert somewhere else in the code (like an alert) it gets executed after loading. Does this mean my function is in the wrong place?

Comment: I really am not sure, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
muteaudio = function(){
    alert("it works");
};
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ngn0Lfmf/

Not sure why your function doesn't work though

Comment: @arodebaugh Yes, that's for comparison, maybe I should have made it more obvious.